# Is there a way for a ranger's pet to deal magic/ranged damage?

Tags: dnd-4e, ranger

We've got a **ranged** beastmaster ranger with a raptor pet that has been re-fluffed as a phoenix. Said ranger is *really* keen for his pet to be doing lots of attacks, so we've houseruled Twin Strike to be one ranged attack from him, and one melee attack from his pet (which, frankly, I think is a nerf to the power, but he's excited and that's what counts).

Now he's looking for ways for his phoenix to do fire damage. I'm thinking maybe letting his phoenix "carry" a magic item with a daily power that does close burst 1 fire damage, or something like that.

Any suggestions on what items would be reasonable for adding phoenix-like powers?

Comment: I've edited out your last question - we don't do idea generation here, we just solve the problems you present to us. To the remainder though, is this fire damage that has to be capable of being done via twin strike, or are fire damage sources that can't be used during twin strike fine?

Comment: I only mentioned twin strike to illustrate that the player is REALLY intent on his pet having an active roll, and that the DM is willing to make allowances to support this.

Comment: No need to break or even bend the rules for this. Just give the player a magic item, that the player wears, that gives bonuses to the pet. You can make up your own magic items.

Answer (score 3):

**Just let it do fire damage.**

As long as you don't allow him to use feats or items to take advantage of his pet doing fire damage, there isn't really any reason to not just make it do fire damage. Having it do fire damage is actually a nerf; while there are monsters with fire vulnerability versus none with vulnerable all, fire resistance is *far* more common than resist all.

**Or let it use his weapon effects.**

I'm on vacation right now so I don't have access to my books to check how animal companions normally gain an enhancement bonus or equivalent attack boost, but beastmaster is such a sub-optimal choice compared to the other ranger options that I really don't think there's any harm in allowing his pet to use his weapon's effects and activate its powers. There *probably* isn't any harm in letting it benefit from all of his equipment (minus enhancement bonuses to attack and defenses); a serious optimizer might find a way to abuse that, but he doesn't sound like the type. If you take this path then he shouldn't be able to equip items on the companion itself (it has a single special slot of its own I believe, though I can't remember any notably good options for said slot).

Comment: Hrm. Perhaps I wasn't very clear. I think he's more interested in powers/flavorful mechanics that would enhance the phoenix's combat capabilities. He really wants to feel like his pet is "cool" (hence why I mentioned the twin-strike rework).

For example, say the DM was going to give us a a +1 Flaming Weapon. Would it be so bad to "enchant" the phoenix's claws and let it use the daily?

Comment: You could also create a magic item that the player wears that explicitly says "Your pet does fire damage" or has minor powers to toggle the pet's damage type, like a Sunblade.